# Microsoft.Bcl.Async crashes app.config with probing

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, async-await

I have a application with an app.config and in there a [probing-element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
When I add the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)-Pack my probing-element is deleted from my appName.exe.config after compilation.

What can I do?

*My app.config:*

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<probing privatePath="bin" />      
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

*My appName.exe.config after compilation:*

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">    
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: I suggest you [contact the package owners](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ContactOwners).